# Discrete math ( graphs, trees and tours)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can someone check with me if my answer is right for this question? 
I got $n(n+1)/2$ .
The question is posted below. 
$\newcommand{\Barbell}{\operatorname{Barbell}}$

For $n$ an integer with $n ≥ 3$, let $\Barbell(n)$ be the graph that is made by attaching with a single edge two complete graphs with $n$ vertices each. A complete graph with $n$ vertices is a graph in which every vertex is adjacent to every other vertex besides itself.
The following question is about $\Barbell(n)$. For an integer $n ≥ 3$, how many edges are in the graph $\Barbell(n)$?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried it. I got n(n+1)/2, but I am not sure. By the way it is not a homework problem. It is just practice problems for midterm.

Comment: Try drawing Barbell$(3)$. Does the number of edges match up with what your answer says it should be?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, given $n\geq 3$ you are given two graphs $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$, each of which is a copy of the complete graph on $n$ vertices, $K_{n}$. The graph Barbell$(n)$ is then formed by choosing a vertex $v_{1}\in G_{1}$ and a vertex $v_{2}\in G_{2}$ and then adding an edge between $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ to connect $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ together.

**Hint:**

How many edges are in $K_{n}$?

$K_{2}$ has $1$ edge.

$K_{3}$ has $3$ edges.

$K_{4}$ has $6$ edges.

In general there are as many edges in $K_{n}$ as there are ways of choosing a subset of size $2$ out of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

If the number of edges in $K_{n}$ is $E(n)$ then the answer to your problem is $2E(n)+1$.

Comment: where is that +1 coming from

Comment: The $+1$ is coming from the edge you use to connect the two graphs. It is the "bar" of the barbell.